# Примеры реализации паттерна Repository

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования

В гугле не нашел хороших примеров реализации данного паттерна.

Comment: А как вы определяете, хороший или нет пример? В гугле их туча.

Comment: http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/03/05/The-Generic-Repository-Is-An-Anti-Pattern.aspx

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, спасибо за ссылку. Не только статья, но и весь блог заслуживает внимания.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Getting-Started-with-dd0e2ed8